# Is there a new (non-legacy) way to export an animated GIF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I've always known that you can use *File > Export > Safe for Web* to export an animated GIF in Photoshop. However, in my current version, it says *Legacy* next to that option, which seems to imply that there's a new and improved, non-legacy way to export animated GIFs.

Is there one? What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It largely depends on what your goal is. The "new and improved" method is okay for high end gif animations. If you're doing say an old school animated gif banner (sadly these do still exist) then I would just use Legacy.

The new method would be to use Photoshop's [Render Video](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-exporting-video-animations.html) functionality and then [Adobe Media Encoder](https://creative.adobe.com/products/media-encoder) to convert it to an animated .gif which will give you much more control:

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old answer... but how in hell did this get 9 upvotes? Adobe Media Encoder absolutely **does not** "give you much more control" making an animated GIF! Color reduction? Dithering? Transparency? Looping?

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called Instagiffer. You can customize frame size, quality and much more, and I have done even minute long gifs that look fine.

[image]